# Equal strings does not match for same values

Tags: java, string

I am matching two java Strings ,It matches most of the equal Strings but for some values it does not match even the Strings are totally same .

```
 public static Person SearchPersonByID(String id)
  {
    for(int i=0;i<personList.size();i++)
    {
    Person p=new Person();
    p=personList.get(i);
    String useride=p.UserId.toString();
    System.out.println(p.UserId+"=="+id);
    if(useride.contains(id)||useride.equals(id))
    {
        System.out.println("Matched");
        return p;   
    }

    }return null;

}
```

I have debugged the program ,although values are exactly same still it is returning null.
Here is the values i want to match ..Kindly help me

```
ahsan7==ahsan7
```

they are same and yet it returns null

---

```
   public class Person {

String Status;
String MobileNo;
String Hobbies;
String PersonName;
String Password;
String LastSeen;
String UserId;
String location;
String Adress;
String EmailId;
String Type;
String ImageAdress;
int port;
DefaultListModel<String> FriendsList=new DefaultListModel<>();

Person()
{
}

 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @staticx Note: This is **not** about comparing strings with `==`. Please look at the code carefully.

Comment: Can you post more of the class?

Comment: Post code that can be tested. As it stands right now, its way to vague to know what's going wrong, if anything at all.

Comment: @Jesper: It's likely it's a localized issue, but the question revolves around comparing strings. This is the crux of the linked question. At any rate, can you answer?

Comment: You should post more of the Person class, mostly what UserId is, also,  since you are comparing useride and id, your debug print statement should probably output useride not p.UserId for consistency.

Comment: Maybe `p.UserId` is not a `String`, but a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`?

Comment: ahsan==ahsan is a print statement .just to look at the values

Comment: Nobody can give you an outright answer, but we can help you debug. The first thing that I'd do is print `id.length()` and `useride.length()`.

Comment: @Jasper. It doesnt matter if it is a stringbuilder or stringbuffer he is doing toString()

Comment: Use break point and check what comes in your camparison

Comment: i debugged ! and values seems to the same ... i used trim and even removed extra inverted commas but problem didnt solved

Comment: So you're saying the method returns `null`?

Comment: @kdgregory it gives when i compared the strings p.userid.lenght() =6      and id.length()=990

Comment: Do a `System.out.println(p.userid);` and `System.out.println(id);`.. report back with your results.

Comment: `p=personList.get(i);` what is personList?

Comment: Just tested your code, it runs fine. You are doing something else wrong somewhere else that you're either unwilling to share or don't think its relevant. I'd suggest you post the whole thing if you want to get this resolved.

Comment: kindly remove the down vote ,i fixed the problem ..i tried best ..Question was not that bad

Comment: i added the answer .Problem is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

length of p.userid is right but the length of argument String id always gives 990 .
I changed the program... I splited a Message String using **Message.Split(,);** and then passed the String as Argument to the function

```
  public static Person SearchPersonByID(String id)
{
for(int i=0;i<personList.size();i++)
{
    Person p=new Person();
    p=personList.get(i);
     id=id.trim();
    String useride=id.toString();
    System.out.println(p.UserId.length()+"    compares   "+id.length());
    if(p.UserId.equals(useride))
    {
        System.out.println("Matched");
        return p;   
    }

}return null;

  }
```

and it works fine

Comment: I think you should figure out why `id` is so large; to me that indicates a problem in your calling code. If you do want to keep the `trim()` in this function, I suggest moving it outside of the loop: only trim once, not every time through. Regardless, +1 for solving your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
userride.equalsIgnoreCase(id); for case insensitive comparisons
userride.equals(id) for case sensitive comparison
```

Probably what you can do is put a debug point at the if() and check the strings you are comparing..

Comment: case is totally same .i even used trim

Comment: Is PersonList is a static object??